# hide some element getting from embedded url in react-calendly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, calendly

i am using react-calendly for embedded another website to my website (using InlineWidget react calendly ). i need to hide some fields like name, email on my webpage that are currently appearing from that ebedded url .please give some suggestion as i don't see any props in react-calendly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the standard name and email fields from the Calendly booking page. Even if you are [prefilling them](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/226766767-Pre-populate-invitee-information-on-the-scheduling-page) from your website, the invitee has to confirm these details when booking, per current design.

Comment: i will add the details and i want to just hide from ui . it is possible right?

Comment: no, it's not possible. There's an obligatory step in the booking UI where the invitee must confirm their details, even if your website is prefilling them, to mitigate abuse.

Answer (score 0):

While Calendly's embed API does not allow you to hide these fields, you can use a tool like cloakist as a workaround. This allows you to display the scheduling page outside of an iframe which will allow you to hide the email field by directly accessing the DOM element.

That said, these fields are you required so you'll need to prefill the field values in the Calendly URL for this to work (example - https://calendly.com/acmesales?email=test@test.com)